# why does OSX add extra '._<filename>' when I tar a directory?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, compression

I'd just like to know why if I "tar -czf" a file/directory, osx adds a:  **._**  for each file? I see these when I untar in linux. Or when I work with the uncompressed project in eclipse as it doesn't like them at all.
I use 10.7.5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OS X's tar uses the [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats) format to store extended attributes and ACLs. tar and Archive Utility also know how to convert the ._ files back to the native formats, but the ._ files are kept if the archive is extracted on another platform or on a non-HFS volume.

You can usually just tell tar to remove the metadata by setting COPYFILE_DISABLE to some value:

```
$ xattr -l file.jpg
com.apple.quarantine: 0002;50d20c48;Tweetbot;
$ tar -cf 1.tar file.jpg 
$ tar -tf 1.tar 
./._file.jpg
file.jpg
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -cf 2.tar file.jpg 
$ tar -tf 2.tar 
file.jpg
```

Information stored as extended attributes:

- Resource forks (since 10.4)

  - Custom icons set in Finder and the images of Icon\r files
  - Metadata in PSD files
  - Script objects stored in scpt files, AppleScript Editor window state
- Information about aliases
- Quarantine status, download URLs
- Spotlight comments
- Encoding of files saved with TextEdit
- Caret position of files saved with TextMate
- Skim notes

You can see ACLs with `ls -le`:

```
$ ls -led /Applications/
drwxrwxr-x@ 146 root  admin  4964 Jun 17 22:53 /Applications/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Comment: Great advice on COPYFILE_DISABLE, solved my problems with those nasty ._ files.

Comment: https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/commit/7cf625f3e1ff2f376d265465f8f97dd5b8953ef2#commitcomment-9636090 draws attention to `--disable-copyfile`

Answer (score -2):

Those files were always there, but they are invisible in Finder (and most Mac OS applications).  See https://superuser.com/questions/212896/

**edit**

That is: these files contain the extended file attributes ... en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes ... and they were created as soon as MacOS gave extended attributes to the files.  So these ._* files were not created for the tar archive.

Comment: NO they're weren't always there as it was something I was working with previously on ubuntu. I guess that osx adds them upon exploding the compressed file onto the system. which of course I didn't know until I  took a cop back to the platform of origin. What I'd like to know is wh it adds them in the first place

Comment: These files contain the extended file attributes ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes