# prevent doubleapple files creation when tarring directories (Snow Leopard)

Tags: snow-leopard, command-line, tar

I'm looking **how to prevent tar from saving** or creating .AppleDouble shadow files and preferably do it in an automated manner. There are a few questions asking [why this happens](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75989/why-does-osx-add-extra-filename-when-i-tar-a-directory?rq=1), but I want a solution that helps me prevent this in practice.

What do I need to do using terminal when I tar a directory to prevent these files from being generated?

The duplicate (linked above) as it has been pointed out shows a whole bunch of lines which I do not understand. I'm pretty new to working with Terminal, so that is probably the reason why I don't grasp it.

```
$ xattr -l file.jpg
com.apple.quarantine: 0002;50d20c48;Tweetbot;
$ tar -cf 1.tar file.jpg 
$ tar -tf 1.tar 
./._file.jpg
file.jpg
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -cf 2.tar file.jpg 
$ tar -tf 2.tar 
file.jpg
```

I just cannot imagine that every time I want to tar a directory I need this bunch only to achieve not getting duplicates.

Regarding the solutions given below in the comments, does it mean that **every time** I want to tar something I have to use that whole line? Or is there a way to tell the system to set this as the default behaviour when tarring files?

Comment: Set COPYFILE_DISABLE to some value, like `COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -cf directory.tar directory`.

Comment: Thanks @LauriRanta I saw that question, but did not understand the answer.

So what you're saying is that every time I tar a folder, I will have to add the COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 ? Isn't there a way to do that automatically each time I tar files/directories?

Comment: I use an alias like `alias tarc="COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar --exclude '\\.DS_Store' -c"`. `alias tar="COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar"` would also make `tar -x` keep ._ files.

Comment: The other question might ask why but the answer on it does answer **how** to stop the odd files so the question/answer is a duplicate not the text now says "This question already has an answer here:"

Comment: Well, with all due respect, but the answer that @LauriRanta gave about making an alias actually does answer my question and looks - imho - a whole lot different from the "duplicate", which says nothing on how to automate this.

Comment: I've re-opened this since we only intend true duplicate questions to be closed. I will need @piet to help edit the question so that all the question is clear (especially why related questions don't help this case) and then put the answer in the answer section and not in the question section. Be sure to elaborate on which answer doesn't help you (perhaps linking to the share button on the answer discussing COPYFILE_DISABLE)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LauriRanta answered the question by giving two solutions.

The first solution is to use `COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -cf directory.tar directory` each time you want to tar a directory without the hidden files.

Her 2nd solution however - and also the one I was looking for - shows how to automate the whole lot by using an alias. If you don't know what an alias is (I didn't) there is a great tutorial available [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_aliases_commands) that shows how to create a temporary alias (only valid for current session) and a permanent alias (stays valid even after turning your Mac off).

I used Lauri's suggestion with a few additions to create a permanent alias:

```
alias tarc="COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar --exclude '\\.DS_Store' -zcf"
```

so next time I want to tar a directory without overhead I only have to write `tarc chosen-gzipped-tar-filename.tgz name-of-directory-i-want-to-tar/` and beam it up to my webhost.

Thanks for all comments and input!