# Why might some files not have resource forks? Does this affect the `tar` utility at all?

Tags: command-line, file, archive-utility

I tarred, and re-tarred, the same directory. 2,560 bytes of metadata is somehow lost in that simple process:

> /tmp$ tar xf workArea.tar
>   /tmp$ tar cf workArea_copy.tar WorkArea
>   /tmp$ ls -l *tar
>   -rw-r--r--  1 jdoe  wheel  **2068480** Mar 19 22:54 workArea.tar
>   -rw-r--r--  1 jdoe  wheel  **2065920** Mar 19 23:27 workArea_copy.tar
>   /tmp$

How can there be data loss???

But then, I un-tarred / re-tarred `workArea_copy.tar`, and there was *no data loss*:

> /tmp$ tar xf workArea_copy.tar
>   /tmp$ tar cf copy_copy.tar WorkArea
>   /tmp$ ls -l *tar
>   -rw-r--r--  1 jdoe  wheel  **2065920** Mar 19 23:38 copy_copy.tar
>   -rw-r--r--  1 jdoe  wheel  **2065920** Mar 19 23:27 workArea_copy.tar
>   /tmp$

I noticed in the `tar` verbose output of when I untarred the original `workArea.tar` that some files did not have resource forks:

> /tmp$ tar xfv workArea.tar
>   x WorkArea/
>   x WorkArea/kjDesc.txt  // <-- where is resource fork?
>   x WorkArea/*._engGrammar.doc*
>   x WorkArea/engGrammar.doc
>   x WorkArea/*._gingers.txt*
>   x WorkArea/gingers.txt
>   x WorkArea/*._intro.docx*
>   x WorkArea/intro.docx
>   x WorkArea/*._myAntenna.doc*
>   x WorkArea/myAntenna.doc
>   x WorkArea/notes.txt  // <-- where is resource fork?
>   x WorkArea/*._notesKj.txt*
>   x WorkArea/notesKj.txt
>   x WorkArea/*._queen.xlsx*
>   x WorkArea/queen.xlsx
>   x WorkArea/trans.txt  // <-- where is resource fork?
>   x WorkArea/*._url.txt*
>   x WorkArea/url.txt
>   /tmp$

However, in the verbose `tar` output I can see that the missing resource fork issue exists in **both** untarring `workArea.tar` and `workArea_copy.tar`. The verbose output is exactly the same.

All files in this tar file were created on my MacBook. Nothing was imported from other file systems.

1. I am sure that 2,560 bytes is metadata. But what metadata? `workArea.tar` and `workArea_copy.tar` both have the same missing meta-data, **yet** they have difference sizes. I don't get it.
2. For that matter, how might some files even end-up with missing resource forks in the first place?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**[Resource Forks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork)** are a part of Mac OS files that were mostly used on Mac OS "Classic" (Pre Mac OS X, E.G. Mac OS 6 - Mac OS 9) In earlier Mac OS, and on the HFS File System (and HFS+) files had two "forks", the "data" fork and the "resource" fork. The data fork is what all files today have; the resource fork was a proprietary data structure from Apple designed for storing images, icons, dialog boxes, code and more in a structured file format.

They're not "metadata", they contained actual program code. Here's a screenshot from the old ResEdit program which was how resource forks were edited

[image: ResEdit Screenshot]

Unix, Linux, and Windows lack a clear analogous data structure like the Mac Resource Fork. In part due to this compatibility issue, Resource Forks are not really used anymore (they're largely replaced with "Bundles")

Because of this, BSD/*nix tools like `tar` do not (by default) handle the resource fork. Therefore, when you run `tar cf`, *you only archive the data fork*

Note that in some versions of OS X, the built-in `/usr/bin/tar` utility will preserve resource forks, bu I can't confirm this for all versions of Mac OS X. If you want to preserve resource forks, look into [`ditto`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html) or make an HFS+ disk image (`dmg`) file

Helpful, but out-of-date information: http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/macosx.html

Comment: Thank you for this information. I also found this http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75989/why-does-osx-add-extra-filename-when-i-tar-a-directory

Comment: HFS+ actually supported an arbitrary number of forks, these were called "named forks". They were deprecated with Mavericks in 2013 and the underlying feature of the HFS+ filesystem (the "Attributes file") was repurposed to support the new extended attributes (xattrs) introduced with Tiger in 2005. All native Mac filesystems from MFS to 
APFS support resource forks natively. As of 2021 they only seem to be used for custom file and folder icons via an `Icon\r` hidden file with no data fork and the image data in a resource fork.